# How to move to right a few spaces in div element?

Tags: html

```
<div>
    item
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
</div>
```

Currently, item and item 1-3 are aligned to left exactly.

```
item
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

How to make it display like this:

```
item
   item 1
   item 2
   item 3
```

Comment: You need to use css for that. Indenting in html doesn't make spaces in webpage

Comment: What's the css to do that? For example, I want sub items to move to right with 4 spaces or something like that.

Comment: Add class attribute for sub items like this: `<div class="sub"> ` and add css: `.sub{margin-left: 2em}`

Comment: You could give them a class and them apply `padding-left: 20px;` or `text-indent: 20px;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use padding and margin to add spacing. You can also check the padding and margin of elements using devtools. Then look at the next option to the `Styles`.

To open devtools:

- <kbd>F12</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + I</kbd>
- <kbd>RMB > Inspect</kbd>

[image]

```css
.pl-2 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* OR

.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
} */
```

```html
<div>
    item
    <div class="pl-2 ml-2">item 1</div>
    <div class="pl-2 ml-2">item 2</div>
    <div class="pl-2 ml-2">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There may be other elements to prevent it from working. It doesn't effect in my code.

Comment: this actually worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by adding css like this-

```
div > div{
padding-left:10px;
}
```

But, it will impact on application's all div. So will would be good practice to add some specific class to parent div and then add style like below -

```
div.my-parent-class > div{
padding-left:10px;
}

<div class="my-parent-class">
    item
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this is the css you're looking for.

```
white-space: break-spaces;
```

```css
div {
            white-space: break-spaces;
        }
```

```html
<div>
item
    item 1
    item 2
    item 3
</div>
```

Comment: For simple scenarios like mulltiple pre-written paragraphs of text, this works.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
One of the drawbacks is in smaller area with longer text, this will break the text and the new line will be non-indented.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div > div{
padding-left:24px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    item
    <div>item 1</div>
    <div>item 2</div>
    <div>item 3</div>
</div>
```

```css
div {
            white-space: break-spaces;
        }
```

```html
<div>
item
    item 1
    item 2
    item 3
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).